# Facebook page/personal profile

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have set up a facebook page for my service, but not using my personal account (I created a new account especially for this purpose).
Now when I log in, I go directly to that page and that is all I see. My question is how can I see the profile itself? Friends, Messages, ect...for the new account I have set up?
Why do I see just the page and not the profile itself??
Please help.

Comment: Sounds like you have a business account.

Answer (score 1):

As @phwd correctly states, it sounds like you're using a business account.

From Facebook's [official help](https://www.facebook.com/help/131976240210052/):

> ## What is the difference between a business account and a personal account?

---

> #### Business accounts:
>
> - Are used to manage Pages and ad campaigns
> - Can't be found in search, send or receive friend requests or build apps
> - Can see public information about other people on Facebook, but can't interact with those people except as a Page
> - Don't have a personal profile tied to them
>
> #### Personal accounts:
>
> - Used to connect with people you know in real life For individual, non-commercial use
> - Can connect with other people, join groups or play social games
>   You may create a business account if you don't already have a personal Facebook account.
> - To get started, you will need to first create a Facebook Page.
>
> Please be aware that managing multiple accounts is a violation of
> Facebook’s Terms of Use. If we determine that an individual has more
> than one account, we reserve the right to disable all of their
> accounts.